# Git reset (soft) all changes relative to master

Tags: git

I have a branch that I have worked on for several days. Lots of commits, and merging in master a few times along the way. Now I want to present the work in multiple branches for review.

So I want to get to a branch that is equal to master, but with all my work marked as ready to commit. Then I will pick a some lines from some files, create a commit and a PR, then create a new branch and commit a bit more. I'm happy (indeed would even prefer) to lose all the previous commits.

I can see it is going to use `--soft` but not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

The easy part is getting into the state you requested.  You want to start by checking out your branch, but detaching from the branch (so it will stay put when you reset, allowing you to easily restore if anything goes wrong).

```
git checkout --detach your_branch
```

Then you just do the reset.  Since you want to commit the changes incrementally, I would use `mixed` instead of `soft`.

```
git reset --mixed master
```

All of your changes are still in your work tree, but they show up as "unstaged"; your index looks like `master`, and you have the `master` commit checked out.  You are still in detached head, so now you need to create the first branch you'll present as a PR.

```
git checkout -b new_branch_1
```

So far so good... but now is the harder part.  You said you want to commit changes based on line ranges.  So you'll have to do something like

```
git add -i
```

or

```
git add -p
```

to interactively stage the code you want in the first commit.  See the `git add` docs for details (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Because that can get really tedious (and error-prone) pretty easily, I don't personally recommend it.  A more typical approach would be to do an interactive rebase of your existing branch.  With that, you can squash or otherwise rearrange the changes in your existing commits, taking advantage of how you originally grouped the commits while still getting to present fewer, better organized commits upstream.  For example, if you ahve

```
x -- x -- x -- O <--(master)
 \         \
  A -- B -- M -- C -- D <--(branch)
```

then you could say

```
git rebase -i master branch
```

which will give you an editor with a TODO list like

```
pick A   first commit
pick B   second commit
pick C   third commit
pick D   fourth commit
```

Then, for example, you could edit this to combine `B` and `C` into 1 commit (`BC`), and to put `D` before `BC`.

```
pick A   first commit
pick D   fourth commit
pick B   second commit
squash C   third commit
```

and the result should be

```
x -- x -- x -- O <--(master)
                \
                 A' -- D' -- BC <--(branch)
```

If you want to end up with multiple branches, independently rooted at `O`, it will be a little trickier (multiple rebase commands), but still doable.

You can find more details about rebase at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

There are down-sides to this approach.  The newly-created commits are untested, so if you want a clean repo you should test each of them.  And conflict resolution can be more challenging with a rebase, since each commit is being replayed in what's almost like a separate merge operation.

But it is another option to consider, and like I said it seems a somewhat more common way to go about it.